# How to refresh a single database table from QuickBooks PHP Mirror?

Tags: php, sql, quickbooks

Am using the mirror code in Consolibyte's QuickBooks PHP framework to keep a copy of a QuickBooks company file info in a MariaDB database.  I am using it in `read-only` mode, so the database cannot reach back in to update QB.

The code appears to work OK, but after using it for some months, noticed some of the inventory counts in the database were different from what a physical inventory report showed in QB.

Would rather not dump the entire database and start over as I'm also saving invoice data, and it takes several hours to repopulate those tables.

Most of the database tables have a `TimeModified` field, so I can tell how long it takes to render a portion of QB's info (Customers, Inventory, etc.) into the database.  Inventory doesn't take that long, so would like to refresh just that table (qb_iteminventory).

Tried just truncating the table and re-running the QWC in `WebConnector`, but that didn't work; the inventory table stayed at zero records.

Digging in a little further, noticed some tables in the database such as `quickbooks_recur`, `quickbooks_queue`, etc.  These seem to be used by the framework to keep track of what's been touched in QB.

Fiddled around with removing records from those (`quickbooks_queue`, for example, has a `qb_action` field with records containing data such as `ItemInventoryImport`), but that had no effect, either.

Did create a new database and pull just the inventory into it, and noticed four of these `housekeeping` tables had recorrds inserted: `quickbooks_dataext`, `quickbooks_log`, `quickbooks_queue`, and `quickbooks_ticket`.  However, no amount of removing records I thought were responsible in the "live" database caused the inventory table to re-populate.

So, the question is, how would one force the framework to refresh all records in the `qb_iteminventory` table?  (Whatever the solution is, imagine it could be applied to the Customer, Vendor, Invoice, etc. tables as well.)

Since it doesn't take that long, either truncating the inventory table and repopulating it from scratch, or just making the framework refresh all the quantity fields would be OK.

Any insight would be most appreciated.  Thanks!